# React Native: Parse HTML and replace anchor tags with links to other pages in app

Tags: react-native

Currently I'm getting some HTML back from an api that has links to outside pages, but also has internal links. So we have something like this:

`<div>Go <a href="https://www.google.com">here</a> to an external link. Or you can go <a href="/contact-us">here</a> to an internal link</div>`

What I want to do is parse that HTML and then if I see that a link has https in it, I will treat it like a normal external link and link outside of the app. If it's an internal link, I want to see where it's going and then send the user to that particular page in the app.

Is this possible?